# 1-lag autocorrelation of AR(2) model

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, autoregressive

Assuma an AR(2) model as $y_t=\phi_0+\phi_1y_{t-1}+\phi_2y_{t-2}+a_t$. The covariance would be $\gamma_l=\phi_1\gamma_{l-1}+\phi_2\gamma_{l-2}$ for $l\geq 2$. The autocorrelation then will be as $$\rho_l=\frac{\gamma_l}{\gamma_0}=\phi_1\rho_{l-1}+\phi_2\rho_{l-2}, l> 1$$
We know that $\rho_0=1$ but I don't know how to calculate $\rho_1$.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: You forgot the error term in your AR(2) model.

Comment: @RichardHardy edited it, thanks.